# IN Keyword in Springboot Elasticsearch

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

Having a hard time finding correct QueryBuilders to build a dynamic search query. One piece I'm really struggling is to find the correct QueryBuilder for IN clause.

In the "careIds" below, I want the NativeSearchQueryBuilder to find all the records who have one or more careId in careIds.

Desired Pseudo code:

```
if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(careIds)) {
    searchQueryBuilder.withFilter(inQuery("CareIds", careIds);
}
```

An equivalent method method name would be

```
findAllByCareIdsIn(final List<Long> careIds);
```

Comment: does `findAllByCareIdsIn(final List<Long> careIds);
` not work?

Comment: It probably will but I'm working on a dynamic query depending on the various number of filters user specifies and will need to use a query builder. Right now, I'm using NativeSearchQueryBuilder and would need something equivalent to findAllByCareIdsIn().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`termsQuery(Field, List<Object>)` was what I was looking for.